# Material time derivative of vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find material time derivative of velocity in Cartesian orthogonal coordinate system. This is acceleration, a vector.

$$\boldsymbol a_i=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{v_i}}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial x_k}{dt} \ \\
=  \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v} $$

But, first term is vector and second term (dot product) is scalar. How this works?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\vec v\cdot \nabla)\vec v$ is a vector since we can write

$$\begin{align}
(\vec v\cdot \nabla)\vec v&=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 v_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\hat x_jv_j\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^3 \underbrace{\hat x_j}_{\text{j'th unit vector }} \underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 v_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}v_j\right)}_{\text{j'th component}}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\mathbf v \cdot \nabla \mathbf v$ shall be interpreted as $(\mathbf v \cdot \nabla) \mathbf v$. Here, $\mathbf v \cdot \nabla$ is a "scalar" operator, so when that acts on the vector $\mathbf v$ we get a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You actually missed up the notation:

vector: $V = V_x \hat I + V_y\hat J + V_z \hat K$

$\hat V = \hat I + \hat J + \hat K$

use chain rule:

acc: $ a = \frac{\delta V_x}{\delta t} \hat I + ... + \frac{\delta \hat I}{\delta t} V_x + ... $

then you wrote V which is a vector as $\nabla V \implies meaningless$ and you expected the result to be a vector!